# Suspend fails (reboot on resume) and no hibernate option

Tags: 10.10, suspend, suspend-resume, resume

Upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 removed hibernate option for me and introduced the problem where by after entering standby (being indicated by blinking amber LED on my laptop) I cannot resume my session. Instead I get a crash and system reboots (crash comes instantly on trying to resume).

Tried clean install to eliminate possibility of an upgrade issue but its still persistent. All latest updates installed.

Tried looking for an answer to this but still no joy. Laptop is Sony VGN-FW41E.

Comment: did you ever get this solved? How? Please update (or delete?) your question - thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have a Sony VAIO VGN-FW25G laptop. Though i have noticed that whenever the laptop restarts on trying to resume, its volume is muted.

Comment: VT reopen. This was closed as EOL 3 years after it was posted. These Q&A's lead here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916924/suspend-not-working-shutting-down-instead https://askubuntu.com/questions/885649/ubuntu-shuts-down-instead-of-suspending https://askubuntu.com/questions/790582/ubuntu-shuts-down-on-suspend https://askubuntu.com/questions/870739/dell-xps13-shuts-down-instead-of-suspending-when-on-battery-power-gnome-16-04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/110398/computer-turns-off-instead-of-suspending-sleeping

Comment: @Zanna the question is already answered with 12 upvotes. The point is you should't close a question with upvoted answers as EOL 3 years after it was posted. I think you pointed that out to me last year. Also look at the rep of the person who edited the question initially and the person who edited the answer with 12 upvotes. They could have closed it in 2011 if anything were amiss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sony Vaio FW350 reboots instead of waking up after sleep/suspend](//askubuntu.com/q/67130) (either way works, but I prefer that one because boot parameters generally go in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line)

Answer (score 13):

If the solution below does not work for you, try this one:

- Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (as root)
- Change the line with:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```

  to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
  ```
- run `update-grub` (as root)

Worked for me... Hope this can help you!

Comment: Works perfectly on my Sony Vaio F11. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I lost my wi-fi connectivity on rebooting afte rmaking above changes. Hibernate worked though!!!

Comment: works on Ubuntu 14.04 as well

Comment: works on ubuntu 15

Comment: What does `acpi_sleep=nonvs` mean?

Comment: Found this: "The ACPI specification wants us to save NVS memory regions during hibernation and to restore them during the subsequent resume.  Windows does that also for suspend to RAM.  However, it is known that this mechanism does not work on all machines, so we allow the user to disable it with the help of the 'acpi_sleep=nonvs' kernel command line option." [source](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/113108/)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar issue (reboot on resume) with a Sony Vaio VGN-FW51ZF by changing the last line of the file `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` from `pm-suspend` to `pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off` (guess it was a problem related with ATI proprietary drivers).

Hope this can help you!