# Resume from suspend occasionally causes a restart

Tags: 11.04, boot, suspend, reboot

Occasionally my pc wont resume from suspend (to ram) properly.

Instead of the expected "resume" the pc just does a normal boot.

My biggest problem is that I have no clue where to look for that error. I am missing a point to start, especially because it happens not very often and I can't reproduce it.

I'm running on 64 bit natty.

My PC:

- AMD Phenom II X4 955BE
- Gigabyte GA-770TA-UD3
- ATI Radeon HD 5770

Comment: I believe this is essentially a bug and should be reported directly to Launchpad.

Comment: To answer the second part of the question: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs has an instruction for filing bugs. Doing so might help improve Ubuntu.

Comment: It may have something to do with the GPU. I recently switched from ATI to Nvidia and since then it never happened again.

Comment: It's not a problem related to GPU or CPU... I'm using an Asus A45V with Intel & Nvidia in it... and sometimes this bug pops up, completely randommely...
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my problem, but my computer did the reboot all the time instead of resuming, not sometimes y hope this helps

this worked for mi before i install ati drivers
Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (as root)

Change the line with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

run command  as root

```
update-grub
```

and this other one worked just fine after installing the ati drivers

"I've solved a similar issue (reboot on resume) with a `Sony Vaio VGN-FW51ZF` by changing the last line of the file `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` from `pm-suspend` to `pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off` (guess it was a problem related with ATI proprietary drivers)."

so thanks for those tips and i hope this save you some time

from
[Suspend fails (reboot on resume) and no hibernate option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option/64408#64408)