# Computer Turns Off instead of Suspending/Sleeping

Tags: suspend, sleep, uefi

I recently assembled a new computer with the second generation Intel Core i7-2600K processor (Sandy Bridge) and solid state drive. The solid state drive is only 60 GB and I have lots of RAM so I did no create a swap partition. Ubuntu is installed on a GUID partition and I'm using EFI boot if that's relevant. My motherboard is the Asus P8Z68-V LE and I currently have the automatic overclocking feature enabled.

Every thing seems to be working fine with this new system at the moment, except I cannot put it to sleep. If I choose "Suspend" in GNOME 3, the computer shuts off and I have trouble turning it on again. Here's what happens when I try to turn the computer on again after it fails to sleep:

1. The first time I push the power button to turn it on again, my monitors won't turn on again and the system doesn't do anything. At this point, I hold the power button to turn the computer off again.
2. The second time I try to turn it on, the UEFI (BIOS) beeps three times and I still don't see anything on the monitors. I have to push and hold the power button again to get it to shut off.
3. The third time I try and turn the computer on, it works okay.

So far I haven't had any problem shutting the system down or booting it up. Has any one else experienced this problem? Or could anyone point me in the right direction to find a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, thank you for submitting a very detailed and well set-out question.

I have a similar system set-up to you and have had almost the exact same situation occur, regarding suspend-resume for ages now.

I just found a fix which seems to work, detailed in a couple of other places including on this site. Suspend and resume problems seem to be rife in Ubuntu, for some reason.

The solution is simple:

- Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (as root)
- Change the line with:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```

  to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
  ```
- run `update-grub` (as root)

As I say; this seems to work for me, so I hope it will work for others, too.

[Suspend fails (reboot on resume) and no hibernate option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option/64408#64408)