# Dell XPS13 shuts down instead of suspending when on battery power - Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

My Dell XPS-13 9350 has been malfunctioning when on battery power. On AC Power, whenever I push the power button to make it suspend activities, it works fine, i.e., restores the previous session when turned back on. However, if I do the same on battery, it spends (a strangely long) time rebooting and, consequently, all the programs were closed. This problem happens even if I remove the AC power for seconds with the lid closed - it is as if the computer had no battery at all.

I've tried making changes to:

> - **/etc/default/grub** (recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option/64408#64408) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110398/computer-turns-off-instead-of-suspending-sleeping)), changing 
>    *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""* 
>     to  
>     *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"*
>
> ---
>
> - **/etc/systemd/logind.conf** (recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815117/my-laptop-shuts-down-when-i-close-the-lid-even-though-its-set-to-hibernate) and [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/ubuntu-16-04-shutdown-hibernate-your-laptop-lid-closed/)), setting 
>   HandleLidSwitch=ignore 
>   HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
>
> ---
>
> - **dconf Editor->org->gnome->settings daemon->plugins->power** (recommended [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/ubuntu-16-04-shutdown-hibernate-your-laptop-lid-closed/)),
>   lid-close-ac-action=nothing 
>   lid-close-battery-action=nothing

These settings prevent me from having to reboot, but obviously I don't want to keep my computer running in a confined space (like my backpack), where it may overheat, not to mention the waste of battery life.

Is there anything else I can try? Can this actually be a software/driver problem or is the only option now buying a new battery?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been reading stuff all over the web, and it seems that uninstalling and reinstalling video drivers should do the trick, about to try it will let u know after

Comment: @prabhath any updates?