# Ubuntu shuts down on suspend?

Tags: boot, nvidia, 16.04, suspend, shutdown

I have ASUS GL552VW laptop with nvidia graphics card and driver nvidia-361 on uefi. Now the problem I am facing is , whenever the computer suspends(Either by clicking manually , or from a long idle ) the computer actually shuts down and restarts when I press keys.

I have tried the following options

1. Uncomment `SAVE_VIDEO_PCI_STATE=true` in `/etc/default/acpi-support`.
2. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = "acpi_sleep=nonvs"`.

But still it shuts down on suspend. When I click suspend , the login screen is seen momentarily and then the PC shuts down. And when I press some keys , its boots again showing the grub menu. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

It's very strange and it may have worked only for me, but whenever this happens to me, I shut down the computer entirely (power off). Upon restarting, the computer suspends/resumes normally.