# Suspend not working: shutting down instead

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 9350 and Ubuntu 16.04. My laptop is now shutting down instead of suspending. It'll occasionally suspend properly, but I haven't found the pattern behind this. Please help... this issue wrecks my work flow.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I got suspend to work for closing the lid and clicking suspend in the top right hand gear icon menu, but not for the power button, by doing the following: 
In dconf: org→gnome→settings-daemon→plugins→power: change button-hibernate, button-power, button-sleep, button-suspend, critical-battery-action, lid-close-ac-action, lid-close-battery-action, and power-button-action to hibernate, while leaving sleep-inactive-ac-type and sleep-inactive-battery-type set to suspend.
This might not work for you because I don't even know how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (as root)
2. Change the line with:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
   ```
3. run `update-grub` (as root)

Above taken from [Suspend fails (reboot on resume) and no hibernate option [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/a/33731/307523) The answer is from 2011 and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` may not work the same in which case modify the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line instead.

---

These other unanswered questions are similar to yours:

- [Ubuntu shuts down instead of suspending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885649/ubuntu-shuts-down-instead-of-suspending)
- [Ubuntu shuts down on suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790582/ubuntu-shuts-down-on-suspend)
- [Dell XPS13 shuts down instead of suspending when on battery power - Gnome 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870739/dell-xps13-shuts-down-instead-of-suspending-when-on-battery-power-gnome-16-04)

Comment: this is a fix for Vaio, unlikely to work for Dell. If it does work, we should close as dupe

Comment: This didn't fix the problem with my Dell XPS 13 9350.

Comment: @CedricEveleigh I've been reading up on this: https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues but it is complicated.

Comment: Perhaps Canonical will eventually fix the problem with an OS update. I just hope it's soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Dell latitude e7270 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My problem was solved when updating my kernel [following the instructions here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus)

This probably means it is an Ubuntu issue and I guess updating your kernel might do the job.