# MY PC restarts when sleep mode entered

Tags: 16.04, suspend, hp, intel, restart

I have a rather serious sleep/ restarts issue with my HP Ellitebook 8440p processor intel core i5. The issue does not seem to depend on the OS, windows and now with ubuntu 16.04. 
After entering the sleep mode, my laptop restarts about two seconds after sleeping. I've tried many things to solve it, but none of them did the job. At the first time there were no such problem. I have the 64 bit version of 16.04 installed. The behavior is independent from a power cable/usb device/ethernet cable being plugged in.
I know there have been several treats concerning sleep/ restarts issues, but none of them provides an answer to my specific case. If you have an answer or even a clue on how to solve this issue, it will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it happens under both Ubuntu and Windows, then it seems like a hardware issue.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283324/waking-up-from-pm-suspend-results-in-full-restart

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with my Lenovo Laptop that runs on Ubuntu OS.

When I close my laptop lid or press sleep it goes to suspend mode completely and it is normal, But when I open lid and press any key Ubuntu reboots.

I search lots of stuff for this solution and I got a solution that work fine for me, Let me tell you what I was done...

1. First you have to edit `/etc/default/grub` file

> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

2. Look for the line

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

3. Replace above line with

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"

4. Just Save file and close it.
5. Now you want to update configuration of boot loader

> sudo update-grub

6. After that reboot your system.

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me. i have no directory named grub in etc directory instead the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" is found in the file named grub under the path /usr/share/grub/default/

Comment: I am so sorry for my mistake I just edited my answer. You can now try this to fix your problem. I am mistake because I didn't read you are using ubuntu 16. Sorry for that.

Comment: Does not work for me either. You must be hitting a very particular case of this problem.

Comment: this doesnt work for me either ubuntu 17.10. Mine reboots when I re-open the lid.

Comment: did not ye solved still

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved it. I upgraded the BIOS and reset CMOS setting by removing CMOS battery and waited for 30 minutes then i put the battery back again. The problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the CMOS battery and then put it back again worked for me. It basically resets everything in the BIOS, I had to correct the time when it turned on.

Removing CMOS was an extremely painful process for my laptop Dell E5470 (took 2-3 hours): https://youtu.be/kB0SECWNg20