# Laptop boots on waking up after suspend - Ubuntu 22.04 - Asus VivoBook S14 X430UA

Tags: 22.04, suspend, asus

I am new to ubuntu community,

On my Asus Vivobook S14 I am not able to resume after the system gets suspended (automatically or manually), system undergoes boot on wake-up.
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz

please let me know anything more required

I have already tried updating grub parameter GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

AND

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rdrand=force"
```

as per

[MY PC restarts when sleep mode entered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888349/my-pc-restarts-when-sleep-mode-entered)  and   [Ubuntu 22.04 : Laptop don't wake up after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480155/ubuntu-22-04-laptop-dont-wake-up-after-suspend?newreg=9fda0526528c4cedae3ff11398d7f5bd)

Output for command: `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'`

```
-- Boot fc4905d21fe84f18ada48ee1657e03cb --
Jan 01 09:03:38 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jan 01 09:03:38 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jan 01 09:03:41 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-logind[754]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1704081252.0741] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1704081252.0743] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA ModemManager[804]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1704081252.0750] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1704081252.3056] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1704081252.3841] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 01 09:24:12 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-sleep[4127]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
-- Boot 0ea673f65e094c44878a03852fcac2e1 --
Jan 01 12:01:39 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jan 01 12:01:39 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jan 01 12:01:42 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-logind[761]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1704091904.5579] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1704091904.5581] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA ModemManager[806]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1704091904.5587] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1704091904.7646] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 12:21:44 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1704091904.8387] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 12:21:45 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 01 12:21:45 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 01 12:21:45 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-sleep[1579]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jan 01 12:21:45 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Boot 550c570eb0cc4839ad4519d39835fce7 --
Jan 01 20:41:02 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jan 01 20:41:02 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jan 01 20:41:05 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-logind[762]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
-- Boot 981d618e62fd4162a98e9b44c766ab93 --
Jan 01 21:12:08 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jan 01 21:12:08 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jan 01 21:12:11 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-logind[754]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jan 01 21:35:35 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1704125135.6120] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 01 21:35:35 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA ModemManager[798]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Jan 01 21:35:35 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1704125135.6121] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 01 21:35:35 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1704125135.6123] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 21:35:35 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1704125135.9716] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 21:35:36 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1704125136.0333] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 01 21:35:36 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 01 21:35:37 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 01 21:35:37 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-sleep[5516]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jan 01 21:35:37 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Boot 9654ff3a7cfa4966ae5371eace3aebbc --
Jan 01 21:36:07 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jan 01 21:36:07 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jan 01 21:36:10 asus-VivoBook-S14-X430UA systemd-logind[778]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
```

Comment: You could try to see things that happened just during the previous boot with
``` lang-bash
journalctl -b-1
```
and then press the <kbd>&gt;</kbd> key to scroll to the end of the log - all actions are logged there, not just lines containing the words "sleep", "suspend" or "resume" so this could be more interesting to find about problems with the previous resume process.

Comment: Was it able to resume from sleep before updating the kernel? Have you tried an older kernel?

Comment: there's a small chance this is this problem https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/system-freezes-if-left-unattended/47493/3