# my laptop freezing when trying to hibernate

Tags: hibernate, 17.04, sony

When I type

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

My computer (Sony Vaio VPCEB1E9J) doesn't hibernate and instead freezes up. I have to do a hard reboot to gain control of the machine again. Furthermore, I do not use any btrfs partitions. I also use a swap file.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: How big is your swap? Maybe it's too little.

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122) is any use

Comment: Do you really need to hibernate? Suspending is what users look for usually. In a modern PC hibernating often takes longer that simply shutting down and powering up normally.

Comment: Give this a try (VIAO users only) https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option/33731#33731

Comment: ChemiCalChems, my ram is 6G and swap is 12G.

Comment: MichaelBay, yes, I really need it.

Comment: Zanna, In your answer you mention that  "If that fails, begin troubleshooting". How to start troubleshooting?

Comment: @user692175 Yes, we really really really require hibernation. For laptop users it might be considered an essential feature, particularly when power saving support is also lagging (fair enough, it is a free OS). I understand that Linux is primarily a server OS, but that is not how Ubuntu is presented. There may be reasons, but personally I fail to understand it seems to have had such a low priority the last decade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, given that you're using a swap file, can we assume that you're currently configuring your `grub` file with both `resume` and `resume_offset` tags? To review these requirements, check out the Arch reference here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file (much of the text will still be relevant for Debian/Ubuntu).

That said, I had a hard time myself getting hibernate to work with my Dell XPS 9560. The issue I had appears to have been ACPI-related, and I could only hibernate if I had completely disabled ACPI in the kernel (`acpi=off`).

It turns out that more recent Ubuntu kernels now ship with ACPI rev. 6 support (where compiled with the CONFIG_ACPI_REV_OVERRIDE_POSSIBLE flag). Not sure exactly when this flag was getting compiled into the kernel, but I suspect recently (>4.10.0-20 or so?).

Regardless, forcing ACPI to use rev. 5 (`acpi_rev_override=5`) in `grub` seems to resolve my hibernation issues.

Worth a shot...

Rich