# Ubuntu rebooting after suspending

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, suspend, support

Recently I've setup a system to be able to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22. Generally when my computer starts up I can hear the fan whirring up, but if I were to suspend and try to wake it. I would first hear the fan whir up only to die back down, then whir up again after maybe a second or two. After which I'd get met by the GRUB menu. I should also say my Windows 10 side has no issues sleeping/suspending.

Syslog

```
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware suspend[4314]: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware logger[4314]: <13>Dec 15 00:19:03 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Dec 15 00:19:03 alienware /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1294]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Dec 15 00:19:04 alienware systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 15 00:19:04 alienware systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 15 00:19:04 alienware systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec 15 00:19:04 alienware systemd-sleep[4331]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
-- Boot <some hash here> --
<Seems to be a normal boot from here on out>
Dec 15 00:19:48 alienware kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic root=UUID=2546a72a-1c48-4cc7-a7ba-34b769cd5ffa ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Dec 15 00:19:48 alienware kernel: secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Dec 15 00:19:48 alienware kernel: secureboot: Secure boot disabled
```

Hardware Information

```
System:
  Host: alienware Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Alienware product: Alienware Aurora R11 v: 1.0.21
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Alienware model: 0N43JM v: A00 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Alienware v: 1.0.21 date: 07/04/2023
CPU:
  Info: 10-core Intel Core i9-10900 [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 3506
    min/max: 800/5200
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER] driver: nvidia
    v: 535.129.03
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.129.03
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  Device-2: Realtek Killer E3000 2.5GbE driver: r8169
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 51.27 GiB (5.5%)
Info:
  Processes: 409 Uptime: 22m Memory: 31.14 GiB used: 3.12 GiB (10.0%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

I'm not sure if this is the reason but after looking through more of the log I found this difference from when the desktop was suspending correctly compared to now.

Old logs

```
Dec 12 20:05:47 alienware systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 12 20:05:47 alienware systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec 12 20:05:47 alienware systemd-sleep[8972]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...

Dec 12 20:05:47 alienware kernel: [ 1749.389712] PM: suspend entry (deep) <--------- This line doesn't exist in the newer logs

Dec 12 20:05:47 alienware kernel: [ 1749.391667] Filesystems sync: 0.001 seconds
Dec 12 23:58:23 alienware kernel: [ 1749.392412] Freezing user space processes
Dec 12 23:58:23 alienware kernel: [ 1749.394229] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Dec 12 23:58:23 alienware kernel: [ 1749.394231] OOM killer disabled.
Dec 12 23:58:23 alienware kernel: [ 1749.394232] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
```

New logs

```
Dec 15 00:03:54 alienware systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 15 00:03:54 alienware systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 15 00:03:54 alienware systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec 15 00:03:54 alienware systemd-sleep[11483]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
>>>> That line isn't here
-- boot hash --
<boot procceeds like normal>
Dec 15 00:04:36 alienware systemd-modules-load[403]: Inserted module 'lp'
Dec 15 00:04:36 alienware systemd-modules-load[403]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
```

I've also tried fixes from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24048/suspend-fails-reboot-on-resume-and-no-hibernate-option) to no avail.

Edit: I've forgotten to mention that I've reinstall my GPU drivers and upgraded my BIOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens with my laptop. Looks like it fails to wake-up and simply restarts. It started happening since kernel update from 6.20.0-37 to 6.20.0-39. You can try to downgrade kernel, or try to boot from grub using "advanced boot options" and choose older kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately this hadn't worked for me, but what did end up working was just re-installing my nvidia drivers. I had to reinstall them due to a separate issue trying to connect an old HDD to my computer, but thanks for the help nonetheless!